# Как в opencv преобразовать кадр, хранящийся в объекте класса Mat при получении кадра с веб камеры в jpeg? С++

Tags: c++, opencv, jpeg, web-камера

Как в opencv преобразовать кадр, хранящийся в объекте класса Mat при получении кадра с веб камеры в jpeg не выводя в файл? Мне нужно отправлять полученный jpeg по сети, по этому нужно получить его внутри программы и знать размер байтового буфера, как это сделать?

```
#include <opencv2/core/utility.hpp>
#include "opencv2/videoio.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
using namespace cv;

int main() {
    Mat frame;
    VideoCapture cap;
    cap.open(0);
    cap >> frame;
    return 0;
}
```

Что нужно добавить в следующий код?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для этого можно использовать функцию `cv::imencode` из модуля `imgcodecs`. Использование тривиальное:

```cpp
std::vector<uchar> buf;
cv::imencode(".jpeg", image, buf);
```

Есть еще и четвертый аргумент: параметры сериализации, в данном случае они пустые